# Appium Framework

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-java

Appium

We are trying to create a framework for Appium. We use Cucumber. We chose the Amazon site for testing purposes. The problem is that when I create the locaters in the `StepDefinitions` Classes, everything works fine. But we added locators to Pages classes to be more professional. After using the Pages class as an object in the `StepDefinitions` class, we call the locaters, but they do not work. I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` error. I think the problem is with the driver, maybe I'm skipping a very simple step but I couldn't find an up-to-date source. I would be glad if you could suggest a solution for me.

[image: Pages Class]

[image: Driver Class]

[image: StepDefinitions Class]

[image: Exceptions]

I tried different drivers, checked Google Chrome updates, checked dependency versions, tried with different framework configurations. What do you think I missed?